# Get current column width and height programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I'm trying to get the width and the height of a grid programmatically, In a UserControl.

Here is my `XAML` grid:

```
<Grid Name="BallGrid" Background="DarkBlue" Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

But both of these:

```
double width = BallGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth;
double height = BallGrid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight;
```

return 0,

and these

```
double width = BallGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width.Value;
double height = BallGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height.Value;
```

return both return 1.

I'd like to know the actual width, preferably in the same units as margin sizes. How can I get these values programmatically?

The column values are queried in a ProgessChanged method, that is called by a BackgroundWorker every 50 ms, maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you querying these properties after control is rendered?

Comment: They are called from a ProgressChanged method, I don't know if it has been rendered yet, probably not by the looks of things...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you use `ActualWidth`/`Height`, here those properties are a bit lazy:

> When you add or remove rows or columns, the [ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.actualwidth.aspx) for all [ColumnDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.aspx) elements and the **ActualHeight** of all [RowDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.aspx) elements becomes zero until [Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) is called.

So you could probably call `Measure` manually or try to wait for it.

Answer (score 1):

They are valid after the source has been Initialized. You can override `OnSourceInitialized` to know when that has occurred.

Comment: Where can I find the OnSourceInitialized method? OnInitalized gives the same results.

Comment: I tried OnInitialized first, it didn't work for me. Type 'override ' (override plus space) and Intellisense will prompt you for the method you want to override, select it and Intellisense will add the entire method, body, and base call. Gotta love Intellisense!

Comment: There is no OnSourceInitialised, or at least, my intellisense isn't finding it.

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork This would be a method on the Window class, which is the source of the "source".

Comment: Ah, I'm inside a user control >_>

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork from there you could subscribe to the Window's SourceInitialized event.

Comment: I don't have a reference to the Window t_t. w/e I guess I understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

try `BallGrid.RenderSize.Height` and `BallGrid.RenderSize.Width`

Comment: Well that probably means that your grid has not been rendered yet. If you still want the size then you could try `BallGrid.DesiredSize.Height` and `BallGrid.DesiredSize.Width` but this might not be the size with which it is rendered.